# In Jasmine, how to inject a new factory/service for each test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, tdd

Premise: I'm perfectly aware that services and factories are Singletons.

How can I reset the injected factory for each test?

This is my sample code:

```
describe('Test', () =>  {

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    var $scope: Registration.IRegistrationCardsScope;
    var workflow : Workflow.Registration;

    beforeEach(inject(($injector) => {                          
        $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();

        //injecting with angular, this should be a different factory each time, not a singleton
        workflow = $injector.get("registrationWorkflow");

        //actual workaround thanks to typesript, reinitializing factory manually instead of injecting
        //workflow = new Workflow.Registration(); 

    }));

    it('test factory 1', () =>  {
        workflow.getVariable(); // returns undefined <-- correct;
        workflow.setVariable(1);
     });

    it('test factory 2', () =>  {
        workflow.getVariable(); // returns 1 <-- wrong;
        workflow.setVariable(1);
    });

})
```

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: beforeEach(inject(($rootScope, registrationWorkflow) => {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new(); workflow = registrationWorkflow;
  }));

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but using signature injection like you did is the same as using $injector, I 'll always get the singleton